# iPhone - yet another unsolvable memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

could you take a look at this piece of code coming from "Leaks instruments" : [image]

The tool indicates a memory leak in the string `temp` that is underlined dotted. Or **I release it just after I use it**.

Also, **the responsible library seems to be Foundation**, but yet in the stacktrace this is the last call in my projects. I just want to correct this. Maybe I can't ?

Thanks in advance.

---

The leak did not show up **with the device**.

I'm sorry but I forgot to mention the leak appeared in the simulator. I'm still curious if this is a known bug or something ?

Comment: You don't actually need `temp`, you can do this:
`NSString *val = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, j)];`

Comment: Actually I tested all kind of possibilities. It's my mate that told me to give this a try. I tested with your code, with :`[NSSTring stringWithFormat:...`, and other stuff...

Comment: Actually I think it's a known bug... the stacktrace points to the NSStringPlaceHolder class. It's used when creating string with variable placeholders : `%s`, `%@`... What do you think ?

Comment: Why don't you try using sprintf and write to a C string instead as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes leaks appear in the simulator that do not appear on the device.  If you don't see a leak on the device, do not worry about it.

However I would recommend you look into using the autoreleased versions of the various string calls you are using, like `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` and simply saying:

```
temp = @"%s";
```